# Prove that $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+⋅⋅⋅+a_1x+a_0, x^n=O(f(x))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that if $f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ and $a_n\neq0,$ $f(x)=\Theta(x^{n})$. I have known that $f(x)=O(x^{n})$, but I don't know how to prove $x^{n}=O(f(x))$. Please offer me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: If $Ca_n>1,$ then $Cf(x)-x^n$ has a positive first coefficient, and thus $Cf(x)-x^n>0$ for $x$ large.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be $a_n \neq 0$ instead of $a_0 \neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = Cf(x)-x^{n}$. We know that $g(x)$ has $n$ roots. Let $x_{0}$ be the largest one. If $Ca_{n}>1$ then we know that $g(x)>0$ for $x>x_{0}$. This means that $C f(x)>x^{n}$ for $x>x_{0}$. If you can find a positive $C$ such that $Ca_{n}>1$ then you are done.

Comment: I wonder how to guarantee that $Cf(x)-x^{n}>0$. If a certain coefficient in $a_{n-1} , a_{n-2} ,...,a_0$ is negative, then its whether $Cf(x)-x^{n}>0$ is uncertain.

Comment: I've modified the wording of my answer to clarify this.